# Syntax error on a condition into an apex:inputText value

Tags: visualforce, inputtext

I have an apex:inputText in wich I want the value to change when an Id is null or not null. I wrote that :

```
<apex:inputText value="{!IF(droitId!=null,droit.Oeuvre__r.Name,nomOeuvre)}"></apex:inputText>
```

(nomOeuvre is a variable I declared in my controller)

I tried with double quotes or simple quotes on the attributes, but I always get an error like `"syntax error : value ')' missing ' or 'syntax error : value ' missing'`

I was pretty sure that my syntax was right, and when I search for it, I found the same syntax than the one I use... If you have any idea about that kind of error, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the issue is you can't use expressions for the `value` attribute. From the [VF developer's doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputText.htm)

> A merge field that references the controller class variable that is
>   associated with this field. For example, if the name of the associated
>   variable in the controller class is myTextField, use
>   value="{!myTextField}" to reference the variable.

so, you could do the following instead:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!droit.oeuvre__r.name}" rendered="{!droitId<>null}"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!nomoeuvre}" rendered="{!droitId=null}"/>
```

Comment: thank you, it's working this way, I'll keep your answer in mind ;)